# Bootstrap v5.2 radio inputs/labels will not align when label text is larger than default

Tags: radio-button, label, bootstrap-5, vertical-alignment

I cannot align Bootstrap v5 radio buttons vertically when the label is larger than the default text. For example, if the label is heading size 3, the radio button is at the top of the div.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="btnColour" onchange="generateBtnCode()">
   <input class="form-check-input" name="btnColour" id="btn-secondary" type="radio" value="secondary">
   <label class="form-check-label" for="btn-secondary"><a class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary Grey</a></label>
</div>
```

[Primary Bootstrap button as an input label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hchSC.png)

I have tried playing with vertical-align, line-height, margin-top, margin-bottom, toggling with all these things on the div, the input and the label. NOTHING WORKS.

https://codepen.io/madmanalphonsus/pen/JjBRELK - A codepen I've setup with a few different radio buttons. If anyone can figure this out I would be very appreciative.

Thanks

Tim

Adjusting the following in combination with the label/input/div:

- Vertical align
- Line Height
- Margin
- Padding
- Justify-content
- Screaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goodness. I found the answer!

```
div.form-check-inline{
   line-height: 1.5rem;
   display: inline-flex;
}
label{ 
   line-height: 1.5rem;
   margin-left: 5px;
}
input[type='radio'] {
   line-height: 1.5rem;
   margin: auto;
}
```

So the trick is:

- that the div incasing the input and radio button needs to be inline flex
- all 3 elements (div, radio button, label) have to have the same line height.
- The radio button margin: auto,
- and the margin-left on the label is there to have a pocket of space between the label and input.

Then if you have an element inside the label. For example in my code builder I have a  element inside the label, you have to remove the pre-existing margins for that element type. So with bootstrap add class="m-0" or inline styles style="margin: 0px;".

See my working codepen here - https://codepen.io/madmanalphonsus/pen/JjBRELK

Answer (score 4):

Add these classes `d-flex align-items-center` to the div

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://uq-itali.github.io/uqlearnx/medi7100/css/customStyles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://uq-itali.github.io/fontawesome-v6.1.1-free/css/all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://uq-itali.github.io/uqlearnx/medi7100/bootstrap-5.2.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>


<div class="d-flex align-items-center form-check form-check-inline" id="btnSize" onchange="generateBtnCode()">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="btnSize" id="btnSize1" type="radio" value=" btn-sm">
  <label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label fs-1 m-3" for="btnSize1">placeholder</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer works IF you don't need them to stay inline. If you're happy for them to stack, then they stack and the buttons align. Nice fix!